# I want a updated value to change the slider handle placement and update "rating score"

Tags: javascript, html, slider, onload, onload-event

Note: I am very new to web development

Overview of my objective:
I have a data that has a value that changing every week. This value will determine where the slider handle will be position in the slider and update the current "score." For example, if this week the value is .25, the handle should be at .25 on the slider and the rating should be ".25" All this should happen once the user gets to this page.

What I have right now:
I'm still working on how to get the value to lets say this weeks value is ".5"
I was researching and saw the "onload" would be my best option to change the rating score, but it doesn't update the score. As for the slider handle, I tried to get update the rating score first then insert that value onto the slider's value="", but nothing happen.

HTML:

```
<p id="rating" onload="myFunction()">Rating: <span id="ahtaRating">0</span></p>
<input type="range" min=".00" max="1" value="ahtaRating.value=value"   class="slider" id="myRange" step=".01">
```

javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = .5
return document.getElementById("ahtaRating").innerHTML = x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This snipped should help you.
I've also added a button to reset, and an event onchange so that when you use the slide it also change the html span value.

```js
        function myFun(val) {
          document.getElementById("ahtaRating").innerHTML = val;
        }
        
        function initRange(val) {
          document.getElementById("myRange").value = val;
          document.getElementById("ahtaRating").innerHTML = val;
        }
```

```html
<body onload="initRange(1);">
  <p id="rating" >
    Rating: <span id="ahtaRating"> 0.5 </span>
  </p>
  <input id="myRange" type="range" step=".01" min=".00" max="1"  onchange="myFun(this.value);" class="slider"  >
  <button onclick="initRange(0.5);">reset</button>
</body>
```